# Archivo conflictivo después de la depuración

Tags: c#, vscode, depuración

Buenas tengo problemas con el editor Visual Code que cuando creo una nueva librería de c# con el comando `dotnet new classlib` o
`dotnet new classlib -f netcoreapp3.1`Al momento de compilar la app me salen distintos errores de atributos duplicados y archivos conflictivos.

[image: Esto es lo que sale cuando compilo por primera vez]

[image: Esto sucede cuando compilo por 2da vez]

[image: Este es el código de una clase de la librería]

[image: Aquí se puede ver que estoy referenciado con la librería]
[image: Aquí los respectivos errores]
[image]
[image]
Ya he intentando muchas formas como Reinstalar Visual Code, Reinstalar las Extensiones que tengo etc.. El problema solo me sucede a mí porque estoy trabajando en equipo con otro compañero y a el todo le va sin problemas y ya probé con otros proyectos y pasa lo mismo siempre que importo una librería de clases.

PD: Gracias por dedicar unos minutos de su tiempo :).

Answer (score 0):

https://elanderson.net/2017/06/duplicate-system-reflection-assemblycompanyattribute-attribute/

Revisa este enlace, se explica que el error ocurre cuando se trata de convertir proyectos mas viejos a nuevos proyectos de .net core.

Te recomiendan 3 posibles opciones

1 borrar el fichero assemblyinfo.cs

2 eliminar los elementos en conflicto del fichero assemblyinfo.cs

3 editar el csproj y desactivar la generación de los atributos que causan el problema. Este fichero csproj entre otras cosas guarda los ensamblados que se utilizan en el proyecto

Comment: Gracias por la información ya mismo me lo leo

Comment: si te sirvio me lo haces saber porfavor

Comment: Lo acabo de intentar y no me sirvió, tal vez si el problema surgiera utilizando Visual Studio seria fácil resolverlo pero creo que el problema esta en VSCode cuando me genera el proyecto de consola. Pero muchas gracias darme un solución :)

Comment: y pq no usas entonces el vs

Comment: Porque estoy haciendo un proyecto con otro compañero que usa Vim y la viene bien usar si uso un editor de codigo que VS para facilitar el trabajo.